# Adding an extension method "Move" to generic List(Of T)": T is not defined

Tags: vb.net, extension-methods

I would like to add the "Move" method as an extension method to the "List(Of...)".

I would like to add this to the generic list, not to a specific list.

My approach is this:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module ExtensionMethods
    <Extension()>
    Public Sub Move(ByRef uBase As List(Of T), ByVal index As Integer, ByVal newIndex As Integer)

        Dim item As T = uBase.Item(index)
        uBase.RemoveAt(index)
        uBase.Insert(newIndex, item)

    End Sub

End Module
```

The compiler doesn't accept the "T" in the lines "uBase As List(Of T)" and in " Dim item As T ="

What should be used here?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You might want to do `Import System.Collections.Generic` at the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, don't use `ByRef` on the target parameter.  I'll expand on that later, because I want to skip to what will fix your compilation error.

Second, in order to have a type argument `T` in `List(Of T)`, it has to exist in the method definition, so you need `(Of T)` on the method.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module ExtensionMethods
    <Extension()>
    Public Sub Move(Of T)(ByVal uBase As List(Of T), ByVal index As Integer, ByVal newIndex As Integer)
        '          ^^^^^^

        Dim item As T = uBase.Item(index)
        uBase.RemoveAt(index)
        uBase.Insert(newIndex, item)

    End Sub
End Module
```

---

**Rule**: An extension method should never<sup>**</sup> accept the target instance using `ByRef`.

**Exception to the rule: Certain value (`Structure`) types may need to be passed by reference to achieve reference type-like behavior (although value types should be immutable if at all possible) or to achieve better performance (in C#, you use the `in` keyword so the compiler prevents mutation of the instance).

Take this extension method, for example:

```
Module ExtensionMethods
    <Extension()>
    Public Sub ConfuseMe(Of T)(ByRef list as List(Of T))
        list = New List(Of T)
    End Sub
End Module
```

```
Dim myList As List(Of Integer)
Dim myList2 = myList            ' A copy of the reference, but only one list object involved.

myList.Add(0)
myList.Add(1)
myList.Add(2)

myList.ConfuseMe()              ' Call an extension method that can MODIFY myList
```

`myList` no longer points to the same instance.  `myList2` points to the original instance while `myList` points to the new one created in `ConfuseMe`.  There's no reason the caller should expect that to happen.

So why would you ever do something like this?  You probably wouldn't.  But based on some of the comments and the confusion between references vs. references to references, I could see it accidentally happening.  Using `ByVal` prevents it from ever becoming a difficult-to-track-down bug.

While it's possible in an extension method, you can't do that with a regular instance method.

```
Class TestClass

    Sub ConfuseMe()
        Me = New TestClass()  ' Not possible on a Class
    End Sub

EndClass
```

```
Dim x As New TestClass()
x.ConfuseMe()              ' You wouldn't expect 'x' to refer to a different instance upon return
```

You can't do that.  It won't allow you to assign to `Me` (again, value types are the exception), and you wouldn't expect `x` to point to a new instance after a call like this.

By the same token, it doesn't make sense to do it in an extension method, where the purpose is to behave like an instance method.  And since you don't *need* to change the caller's variable, there's no need to take a reference to it.  Just deal with the direct reference to the object instance by accepting it with `ByVal`.

Comment: @madreflection But I DO want to change the object. I don't want to work with a copy, and Byval does create a copy. Can you please explain that in answer-addon as well, please? Byref sounds exactely like what I need.

Comment: You want to change the *contents*, not the instance reference. You don't need `ByRef` to change the contents.

Comment: But "ByVal" creates a copy, right? So it doesn't change the object. Well, obviously it does, but I don't understand why. Everywhere it's written that Byval creates a copy. So in VB6 this wouldn't work: "Sub FillTheArgument(Byval uSomeArg As String)". Only "Sub FillTheArgument(ByRef uSomeArg As String") would work.

Comment: You're confusing the reference with the object itself. Just because I write your name on two lists, doesn't mean I made a clone of you. Your name is just a reference to your corporeal being. There are two references, one on each list. `ByVal` copies the reference (address) of the object onto the stack.  `ByRef` puts a reference to your reference, allowing the method to change your variable.

Comment: When a parameter is passed by value, a copy of what you pass is created.  If the parameter is a reference type then what you are passing is a reference, so a copy of that reference is made.  The new reference still refers to the same object though.  The object itself is not copied.  The parameter is basically just like a variable.  If you assign a `List(Of T)` to a new variable, does that variable now refer to a different object?  Of course not.  Both variables refer to the same object.  A method parameter passed by value is the same.